# How to fetch the network address from IP address without using library

Tags: java, binary, ip

First of all i m a beginner.
I have a method with two parameters, ip address and subnet mask address. This method will return network address.

I know how to get the network address with using java library, something likes `import java.net.InetAddress` or `using apache common library`

But i dont know **how to write without using any libray, just only simple java**, playing with biniary.

Here is my sample code

```
public static String getNetworkAddress (String ip, String subnetmask) throws UnknownHostException {

    byte[] bIP = InetAddress.getByName(ip).getAddress(); 
    byte[] bSB = InetAddress.getByName(subnetmask).getAddress();
    byte[] bNT = new byte[4];

    for(int i = 0;i<bIP.length;i++) {
        bNT[i] = (byte) (bIP[i] & bSB[i]);
    }
    return InetAddress.getByAddress(bNT).toString().substring(1);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `java.net.InetAddress` is part of the *JVM*, not any "library", so what is it what you're asking?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle sorry for my bad question, i means without using java.net.InetAddress (without using any JVM also any other library),,thanks

Comment: *"i means without using java.net.InetAddress (without using any JVM"* in Java you cannot do anything without using the JVM. And not inventing the Wheel another time is also something good in programming.

Comment: If you want to do it with no 'library', as a start point, why do not you check the InetAddress implementation?

Comment: @PedroH sorry for my bad english, how to write without using InetAddress, can you help me please?